# Hadoop own data types

Tags: hadoop, types

I have been using hadoop for quite a time now but I'm not sure why Hadoop uses its own data types and not Java data types ? I have been searching for same thing over internet but nothing helped. please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is because of the serialization & deserialization performance that they provide.

Long version:

The primary benefit of using Writables (Hadoop's data types) is in their efficiency. Compared to Java serialization, which would have been an obvious alternative choice, they have a more compact representation. Writables don't store their type in the serialized representation, since at the point of deserialization it is known which type is expected.

Here is a more detailed excerpt from Hadoop Definitive Guide:

> Java serialization is not compact, classes that implement `java.io.Serializable` or `java.io.Externalizable` write their classname and the object representation to the stream. Subsequent instances of the same class write a reference handle to the first occurrence, which occupies only 5 bytes. However, reference handles don't work well with random access, because the referent class may occur at any point in the preceding stream - that is, there is state stored in the stream. Even worse, reference handles play havoc with sorting records in a serialized stream, since the first record of a particular class is distinguished and must be treated as a special case. All these problems can be avoided by not writing the classname to the stream at all, which is the approach Writable takes. The result is that the format is considerably more compact than Java serialization, and random access and sorting work as expected because each record is independent of the others (so there is no stream state).